# How to execute query output

Tags: oracle, plsql

We have written a  sql that return sum and average of numeric columns present in schema.

Could you please help us if there is there a way to execute the query and queryoutput together in a single query. We don't have create or insert permission.

```
select 'select  avg(' || column_name ||'), sum('||column_name|| '), '|| table_name 
       ||' from '|| table_name ||'   ' ||'union all' 
from all_tab_columns
where data_type= 'NUMBER'
and owner not in ('SYS','PUBLIC','WMSYS','SYSTEM') 
and column_name not in ('BATCHNUM')
```

The output of above query  is

```
select  avg(amt), sum(amt2), table1 from table1   
union all
select  avg(amt2), sum(amt5), table2 from table2
```

---

Here is what we are trying to achieve in a single query

```
schema Tablename  columname   average  sum 
Test    testable   amount       10      1000
Test    testable   amounttrans  100      4000
Test2   transtable  amount       100     5000
```

thank you

Comment: Your first statement doesn't generate an executable query (trailing `union all`). So it cannot be executed automatically, there must be human intervention to edit the statement.

Comment: Could you please guide us to find "SchemaName, TableName, ColumnName, Average, Sum)  for all the tables in a schema that have numeric data type .

Answer (score 0):

You may create a dynamic View( Ask your superuser / dba to create it for you if you don't have permission)

In this example, I'll use few rows from HR schema.You may modify it to add schema name as well using `all_tab_columns`

```
DECLARE
     v_sql CLOB := empty_clob();
    BEGIN

    for rec IN (select 'select '''||table_name||''' as tablename,
         '''||column_name||''' as columname,
                   avg(' || column_name ||') as average,sum('
                         || column_name || ') as "SUM" from '
                         || table_name
                         ||'   ' as qry
                  FROM user_tab_columns --all_tab_columns
    where data_type= 'NUMBER'
    --and owner not in ('SYS','PUBLIC','WMSYS','SYSTEM') 
                        AND column_name NOT IN ('BATCHNUM'
                  )
                        AND ROWNUM < 10
                ) LOOP v_sql := v_sql
                                || rec.qry
                                || ' UNION ALL ';
      END LOOP;
        v_sql := regexp_replace(v_sql,' UNION ALL $');
     EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE OR REPLACE view my_view as ' || v_sql;
END;
/
```

Now, Query the view.

```
SQL> set sqlformat ansiconsole
SQL> select * from my_view;
TABLENAME     COLUMNAME                                           AVERAGE      SUM
REGIONS       REGION_ID                                               2.5       10
COUNTRIES     REGION_ID                                               2.4       60
LOCATIONS     LOCATION_ID                                            2100    48300
DEPARTMENTS   DEPARTMENT_ID                                           140     3780
DEPARTMENTS   MANAGER_ID         154.909090909090909090909090909090909091     1704
DEPARTMENTS   LOCATION_ID       1777.777777777777777777777777777777777778    48000
JOBS          MIN_SALARY        6573.052631578947368421052631578947368421   124888
JOBS          MAX_SALARY         13215.1578947368421052631578947368421053   251088
EMPLOYEES     EMPLOYEE_ID                                             153    16371
```

If you're running Oracle 12c and above, you may use `DBMS_SQL.RETURN_RESULT`

use the the same block above except for these changes..

```
DECLARE
 ..
 v_cur SYS_REFCURSOR;
  BEGIN
  ...
  END LOOP;
    v_sql := regexp_replace(v_sql,' UNION ALL $');
     OPEN v_cur for v_sql;
    DBMS_SQL.RETURN_RESULT(v_cur);
  END;
/ 


ResultSet #1


TABLENAME   COLUMNAME        AVERAGE        SUM
----------- ------------- ---------- ----------
REGIONS     REGION_ID            2.5         10
COUNTRIES   REGION_ID            2.4         60
LOCATIONS   LOCATION_ID         2100      48300
DEPARTMENTS DEPARTMENT_ID        140       3780
DEPARTMENTS MANAGER_ID    154.909091       1704
DEPARTMENTS LOCATION_ID   1777.77778      48000
JOBS        MIN_SALARY    6573.05263     124888
JOBS        MAX_SALARY    13215.1579     251088
EMPLOYEES   EMPLOYEE_ID          153      16371

9 rows selected.
```